# Windows Service doesn't read settings.setting?

Tags: c#, configuration, windows-services, setting

I have a Setting.setting have a setting option : isSent - type int - value : 0

And my code :

```
 if (Settings.Default.isSent =! 0)
                {
                    var info = _text.ReadFile(Settings.Default.FilePath);
                //Do something
                } else
                {
                //Do something
                }
```

I install my Windows Service, start and attach it to Visual to debug, and it always run to

```
var info = _text.ReadFile(Settings.Default.FilePath);
```

But not run to

```
} else
{
//Do something
}
```

like I expect :(

Anyone can explain it and know how to solve this for me ? Appreciate any answer :)

Comment: so the `FilePath` gets the value from the settings correctly then?

Comment: I'm not sure I cant check the value of its while debuging :( But the info got the expected value so the _text.ReadFile must receive correct value from Settings.Default.FilePath.

Comment: don't understand why you can't see the value.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed "if (Settings.Default.isSent =! 0)". Should it be "if (Settings.Default.isSent != 0)". Otherwise visual studio will always report error.

by the way, have you tried to attach your source code to the Service and see the value of "Settings.Default.isSent" at runtime?